# FPGA Timing Constraint for 2 Combinational paths to take the same time

Tags: fpga, timing-analysis

I am trying to do a simple asynchronous FPGA design where I have 2 inputs and 2 outputs, and assign the outputs to the inputs.  I need the delay of both assign's to be near identical.  What timing constraint can I use to set the both to be near the same?

Comment: The delay is dependent on the gate delays if the logic operation involved on each of the operation is different. In case they're the same you can use the set_max_delay constraint on both to ensure that neither does not exceed that value.

Comment: Should combining a set_max_delay with a set_min_delay force all signal to take a propagation in that range?

Comment: Yes that's correct! But what is your intent here? Usually set_max_delay is used when there are clock domain crossings.

Comment: This is a non-standard FPGA design where I need to have it act as a buffer for a few data lines and not skew them.